# create a new permissions level for preventing the downloading the document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement to setup a permission level, where user can only see the document and see  but cannot download or open the document.  I tested with "View Only" which differs from "Read" . After testing i came to know that people with "View Only" can download the documents and see the source. Can i create a  new permission level which will not allow download the document.
help is appreciated

Comment: This is a weird requirement. You want a user to see a document but not open it?

Comment: I think you can not. If a user can see it, He/She can download it.

According to MS, there is a way, configure IRM (Information Rights Management), I found a lot of information, but I can test it, becouse I dont work whit AD on my labs, sorry :|

Comment: thanks for the replies.yes, my customer has these kind of strange struff. they want end users to view the document  but should not be able to download the same.though we have todl them that, if we apply the viewonly permissions they will be able to download.